# Jacobson, Basic Algebra II, Theorem 4.2

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

I would like to show: (Jacobson, *Basic Algebra II*, Theorem 4.2, (3) $\Rightarrow$ (1))

> ($R$ is isomorphic to a ring $\mathrm{End}_\Delta M$ where $M$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a division ring $\Delta$) $\Rightarrow$ ($R$ is simple, left artinian, and non-zero.)

The proof given:

> Using the anti-isomorphism $\mathrm{End}_\Delta M$ with $M_n(\Delta)$, recalling that if $R$ is any ring, the map $B \rightarrow M_n(B)$ is an isomorphism of lattice of ideals, the result follows from simplicity of $\Delta$.

I see $R$ is simple. But how is it left artinian?

My argument:

> This implies we have to consider the left ideals of $M_n(\Delta)$ (I will ignore opposite ring for simplicity). Observe:
>
> (i) $I_{jk} = \{ a : a = A_{jk}, A \in M_n(\Delta) \}$ is a left ideal in $\Delta$. Now $e_{ij} M = _iM_j$, where $_iM_j$ denotes matrix with $i$th row being the $j$th row of $M$, all else $0$. This implies, $I_{jk}$ are identical for $1 \le j \le n$, $k$ fixed.
>
> (ii) We deduce each left ideal is of the form $(I_{11}^n, \ldots, I_{1n}^n)$ where $I_{k1}$ is a left ideal of $\Delta$. <s>So any decreasing chain of left ideal in $M_n(\Delta)^{op}$ induces a decreasing chain of left ideals in $\Delta$.</s>  As there  are only two left ideals in $\Delta$, there is at most a chain of length of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

> So any decreasing chain of left ideal in $M_n(\Delta)^{op}$ induces a decreasing chain of left ideals in $\Delta$.

Well, we already know that there is only one chain of left ideals in $\Delta$ and it has two elements. But there can be chains of left ideals of length $n$ in $M_n(\Delta)$, so you can't create a strictly decreasing chain of ideals in one and get a strictly decreasing chain in the other.

$M_n(\Delta)$ is an $n\times n$ dimensional $\Delta$ vector space, and each left ideal is a subspace. Chains of subspaces can therefore be no more than $n\times n$ deep. As I alluded to earlier, one can actually conclude the chains of left ideals are no more than $n$ deep, but that is beyond what we need.

Comment: I am sorry, actually I think the part you quoted does not really make sense to me now. I updated the post. Do you think my argument is correct? How does one argue what the left ideals are? I think your argument with the subspace is neat. Does your argument imply: any finite dimensional algebra over division ring $\Delta$, is left artinian?

Comment: @CWL yes, a ring that is a finite dimensional right module  over some division subring is necessarily right artinian for this reason. There is not a standard definition for an algebra over a noncommutative ring, so I would not say what you said.